# How to run particular while $timeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I want to make a short `$timeout` in my code, and while that $timeout is active I want to run this bit of code:

```
pbInterval = $interval(progressBar("delay"), 100);
```

I don't necessarily need to use `$timeout`, something else would be fine too. I just want a short delay and run my particular code.

Comment: i guess you want to run a loader in the processing time.. IMO you should do this-

$timeout(function(){
loader.start(); // this function slowly increments the progress bar

NEXT LINE
// do what u want to do here
 NEXT LINE loader.end();
}

Comment: `$interval` expects first argument to be function expression. You are invoking `progressBar` function and this function does not return function expression too hence _It is not working_

Comment: @RayonDabre [This](http://plnkr.co/edit/Fc7dZNb3DNN75kMlrkyz?p=preview) is what I've got so far now, but I only want to run the timer for only **1 second**. How do I get that to work?

Comment: @Goldenowner, Plunker does not work..

Comment: @OP, you do not need `$timeout` here.. Try this: `var counter = 0;
var delayInterval = $interval(function() {
  ++counter;
  console.log("Hello world!");
  if (counter === 10) {
    $interval.cancel(delayInterval);
  }
}, 100);`

Comment: @RayonDabre Doesn't it work? Weird. It does for me, but I got it now, So thanks a lot! Working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Fc7dZNb3DNN75kMlrkyz?p=preview)(I hope)

Comment: Did you try the solution I provided ? http://plnkr.co/edit/JnCQfLYHAqXKk0eqpjJn?p=preview

Comment: @RayonDabre Yes worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$timeout(function() {
  progressBar("delay");
}, 100);
```